# Java program is creating extra columns in csv file

Tags: java, excel, csv, jdbc, config

I am creating a csv file in a JDBC program that pulls data and then writes it to the csv file. The problem is that some of the data comes in like "Birmingham, AL" and when the program sees the "," it is creating a new column when really it should all be in one column. The first 15000 rows come in correctly with no commas, but then some commas start appearing and it is creating new columns where it shouldn't. I was wondering if there was a way to catch and avoid this or to workaround this issue. I hope I'm explaining this well enough. Feel free to ask for more information.

EDIT: Here is the snippet of code that does the work.

```
     while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                    if (value == null || rs.wasNull())
                        out.write("NULL" + ",");
                    else
                     out.write(value.toString() + ",");
                }
            }
            out.newLine();
        }

        out.close();
        writer.close();
```

Comment: paste code snippet responsible for this functionality

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
out.write(value.toString() + ",");
```

try

```
out.write("\""+value.toString() + "\",");
```